# Read-the-docs embed in application

Tags: read-the-docs

new to readthedocs. Digging into trying to see if it's good solution for our organization. We are a B2B SaaS and hardware offering.

I'd like to do 2 things I'm not sure are available:

1. I want to embed readthedocs in our web app.
2. I want to manage access/control for the docs. Some access will be public. External users with access can see more stuff and our internal users can see the most stuff.

Can I do these things with readthedocs? Can someone link me the correct info?

Searched all the documentation but haven't found these answers

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book/technologie recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: HI Derek! You can achieve those two points only with Read the Docs for Business, which starts at USD50/month (see https://about.readthedocs.com/pricing/) since Read the Docs Community does not support access control for the docs: only public documentation.